# Where to place Joomla queries

Tags: joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla. I know that the following query should work correctly, but I have no clue where to place this query? I have added a blank module which can run PHP, but when I place this code there, nothing shows up. I really appreciate if someone can tell me where to place this code to be able to view the query results.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id, name');
$query->from('#__users');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: What do you mean by placed the code in there?  Can you post all the  code for the module?  Can't properly trouble shoot without seeing the code in context.

Comment: Like I said before, I added a "blank" module http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/3668 and added this code to the php section of it, but it did not work. In general, the question is that even without adding extra modules, just using Joomla's included modules, where should I place this code and execute it to get results displayed.

Comment: I added print_r line to my snippet to make sure that no comments will be given on PHP basics. The main problem here is that something else (Joomla related) has to be done.

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, the main problem is the Blank module.  In all honesty, you would be far better served writing your own module.  I would recommend using the mod_custom core module as a template to build your own.  I guarantee with the time already invested and the help of the Stack Overflow community, you'd already accomplished what you needed.  I even downloaded, installed and tried to review the code for the module you're using; and in all honesty its so over kill from a programming perspective I don't have the time or desire to properly reverse engineer.

Comment: Thanks Brian for recommending "mod_custom". I will follow your advise.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 101 - you have the result but now you need to print or echo the result in order to show

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id, name');
$query->from('#__users');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: In fact, I did use print_r function and nothing was printed. Something else (in the Joomla part) has to be done to make the Joomla database access work. The emphasis of the problem here is on Joomla and not on PHP.

Comment: I am puzzled - your code should work fine. Were there any php errors?

Comment: Your module folder should contain moduleName.php and moduleName.xml - if you can install the module then the xml is fine. Inside the .php you can place your code and it will work.